# Kendo UI observable value is not available in other functions

Tags: kendo-ui, bind, observable

I have bind some variables to the input fields on `$(document).ready`

```
var appdetail = kendo.observable({
    addAppName: "TESTAPP",
    addAppId: "13579"

});

kendo.bind($("#formAdd"), appdetail);
```

the form is inside a modalview. When I open the modal view I can see "TESTAPP"  and "13579" as the default values. The problem is, when I click the button, I am calling a function AddRecord using data-click.. and in this function I am not able to get the values of the forms in a way like

```
var application_name = appdetail.get("addAppName");
```

is there a way to make the values available in other functions?

---

I am adding the HTML & JS code.. When click the ADD button, default values (TESTDB & 13579) are not comming to my modalview window. All fields are blank. When I click the Authorize button on the dialog, TESTDB which is the default value is returning as the alert message whatever the dialog input field is.

the current code is

**Javascript :**

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {layout: "mobile-tabstrip", loading: "<h1>Please wait...</h1>"});

var appdetail = kendo.observable({
    addAppName: "TESTAPP",
    addAppId: "13579"
});


kendo.bind($("#formAdd"), appdetail);


//alert(appdetail.get("addAppName"));



function closeModalViewAdd() {
    $("#modalview-app-add").kendoMobileModalView("close");
};


function showWindow() {
  $("#modalview-app-add").data("kendoMobileModalView").open();


}

function addToJson() {
  alert(appdetail.get("addAppName"));
 // console.log(appdetail.addAppId);
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kendo UI Mobile</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link href="../styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Encigo Specific Page Scripts--->           
            <script src="../js/mytest.js"></script>

            </head>
    <body>


<!-- LAYOUT: default --------------------------------- start --------------->
        <div data-role="layout" data-id="default">
                    <header data-role="header">
                        <div data-role="navbar">
                            <span data-role="view-title"></span>
                        </div>
                    </header>

                    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                        <div data-role="tabstrip">
                            <a data-icon="globe" href="#languages">Languages</a>
                            <a data-icon="settings" href="#applications">Applications</a>
                            <a data-icon="contacts" href="#login">Login</a>


                        </div>
                    </footer>
        </div>

<!-- LAYOUT: default --------------------------------- finish --------------->

<!-- VIEW: modelview add --------------------------------- start --------------->

        <div data-role="modalview" id="modalview-app-add" style="width: 95%;" data-show="bindNewDataVar">

            <form id="formAdd">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
                    <li>
                        <label>App Name
                            <input type="text" value="" id="app_name" data-bind="value: addAppName"/>
                        </label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label>App Id
                            <input type="number" value="" id="extapp_id" data-bind="value: addAppId"/>
                        </label>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                    <p align="center"><a data-role="button" style="width: 35%" data-icon="play" align="center" id="buttonauthorize" data-click="addToJson" >Authorize</a><a data-role="button" style="width: 35%" data-icon="rewind" align="center"  data-click="closeModalViewAdd" id="canceldialogbutton" >Cancel</a>

                    <!-- <br><a data-role="button"  data-icon="pause" style="width: 35%" align="left" id="resetauthorization">Reset</a> -->
                    </p>


            </form>

        </div>
<!-- VIEW: modelview add --------------------------------- finish --------------->


<!-- VIEW: applications --------------------------------- start --------------->

        <div id="applications" data-role="view"  data-title="Defined Applications" data-layout="default">

            <p align="center"><a  style="width: 90%" data-role="button" data-rel="modalview" onclick="showWindow()" id="AddApplication" data-icon="add">Add</a></p>

        </div>


        </div>
<!-- VIEW: applications --------------------------------- finish --------------->


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That should work just fine.  See sample... http://jsbin.com/xavoh/1/edit

Comment: Is your observable wrapped in a closure, and your data-click function outside that closure ?

Comment: Dear @Robin Giltner I am trying to make the same but still having a problem. Case 1 : when I put the binding part on the top of the js file like you, the defaults value in the dialog are not comming as if the form is not related to the binding. in this case, when I click on the button it doesn't return the changed valur but the defualt value. Case2 : when I put the binding part inside the showdialog function, the default values are comming. but when I click update it returns an error in console and says Uncaught ReferenceError: appdetail is not defined

Comment: Is there anyway you can post the exact code you are trying to use ?  Either here or at jsbin/jsfiddle/etc. ?

Comment: @Robin Giltner I have added the js and html code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend making use the data-model property of the view and modal-view.

```
<div data-role="modalview" id="modalview-app-add" 
style="width: 95%;" data-show="bindNewDataVar" data-model="appdetail">
```

and

```
<div id="applications" data-role="view"
data-title="Defined Applications" data-layout="default" data-model="appdetail">
```

See working sample at... http://jsbin.com/fezel/1/edit